# Is it possible to recover an broadcast value from Spark-streaming checkpoint

Tags: spark-streaming

I used hbase-spark to record pv/uv in my spark-streaming project. Then when I killed the app and restart it, I got following exception while checkpoint-recover:

> 16/03/02 10:17:21 ERROR HBaseContext: Unable to getConfig from broadcast
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.SerializableWritable
>       at com.paitao.xmlife.contrib.hbase.HBaseContext.getConf(HBaseContext.scala:645)
>       at com.paitao.xmlife.contrib.hbase.HBaseContext.com$paitao$xmlife$contrib$hbase$HBaseContext$$hbaseForeachPartition(HBaseContext.scala:627)
>       at com.paitao.xmlife.contrib.hbase.HBaseContext$$anonfun$com$paitao$xmlife$contrib$hbase$HBaseContext$$bulkMutation$1.apply(HBaseContext.scala:457)
>       at com.paitao.xmlife.contrib.hbase.HBaseContext$$anonfun$com$paitao$xmlife$contrib$hbase$HBaseContext$$bulkMutation$1.apply(HBaseContext.scala:457)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:898)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:898)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1839)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1839)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I checked the code of HBaseContext, It uses a broadcast to store the HBase configuration.

```
class HBaseContext(@transient sc: SparkContext,
               @transient config: Configuration,
               val tmpHdfsConfgFile: String = null) extends Serializable with Logging {

    @transient var credentials = SparkHadoopUtil.get.getCurrentUserCredentials()
    @transient var tmpHdfsConfiguration: Configuration = config
    @transient var appliedCredentials = false
    @transient val job = Job.getInstance(config)

    TableMapReduceUtil.initCredentials(job)
    // <-- broadcast for HBaseConfiguration here !!!
    var broadcastedConf = sc.broadcast(new SerializableWritable(config))
    var credentialsConf = sc.broadcast(new SerializableWritable(job.getCredentials()))
    ...
```

When the checkpoint-recover, it tried to access this broadcast value in its getConf func:

```
if (tmpHdfsConfiguration == null) {
  try {
    tmpHdfsConfiguration = configBroadcast.value.value
  } catch {
    case ex: Exception => logError("Unable to getConfig from broadcast", ex)
  }
}
```

Then the exception raised. My question is: is it possible to recover the broadcasted value from checkpoint in a spark application? All we have some other solution to **re-broadcast** the value after recovering?

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: Check at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35124486/why-reading-broadcast-variable-in-spark-streaming-got-exception-after-days-of-ru/50507569#50507569

Answer (score 2):

Currently, it's a known bug of Spark. Contributors have been investigating on this issue but made no progress.

Here's my workaround: Instead of loading data into broadcast variable and broadcasting to all executors, i let each executor loads the data itself into a singleton object.

Btw, follow this issue for changes https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5206

Comment: Thanks, it works when I initialize the singleton object

Comment: @ Xuan Huy Pham &  @He Bai..  Could you please explain your solution. How executor loads the data itself into a singleton object if I am with in Map function if there is not access to Spark context?

Comment: @Xuan.. I made my changes in a similar way. To create that Singleton Object. I made use of SparkConf. Every time a task is serialized from driver to worker I believe the SparkConf getting Serialized and checks if singleton object is initialized or not. Incase not initialized it initializes else no action. Is it serializeing Sparkconf is a overhead??

Answer (score 2):

Follow below approach

1. Create spark context.
2. Initialize broadcast variable.
3. Create streaming context with checkpoint directory using above spark context and passing on the initialized broadcast variable.

When streaming job starts with no data in checkpoint directory, it will initialize the broadcast variable.

When streaming restarts, it will recover the broadcast variable from checkpoint directory.